# Inserting dynamic text: way to set text format and placement preferences?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, format, dynamic-text

I have a series of maps that I need to insert a footer with the filepath and mxd name.  I see that I can insert these using dynamic text, which is great.  However, the text is always placed in the middle of the layout in a text format I do not like.

Is there a way to set up preferences so when you select "Insert\Dynamic Text\Document Path" the filepath is always placed with preferred settings(lower left, 6 pt font, etc)?

I am building the preferences into our templates so we will have this going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you're looking to place a dynamic text element at a specific place in your layout and have it always display there with specific text properties, then save this as a template...

If you place your dynamic text in your layout, use guides to put it in the correct location:

[image]

Then to ensure it always places to the left side, double-click the text to open the properties.

Ensure the text alignment is left:

[image]

Here you can also set the text properties here to always use whatever font settings you want by clicking 'change symbol':

[image]

Then ensure that when the text grows it grows 'from' the left to right by setting the anchor point:

[image]

Now as when you save this as a template and use it for another layout or in a script, it should always use those text properties...

Answer (score 1):

Arcmap is still bugged (at V10.41) and has been for many years: text anchor points are not honored.
The text will always be anchored bottom right and grow 'up and right' from there which means that multi line text won't work as expected (i.e. if setting the anchor point top left, you'd expect the top line to stay in position and subsequent lines to be placed beneath that: This does not happen)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do for the first part of your question is to create a standard map template for your organization.  [These directions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000002w000000) show how you can create a map template, as well as apply it to your existing maps.